# How to ensure that all projects in a c# solution use same versions of third party library?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I was working on a solution with multiple projects and I updated `Newtonsoft.Json` in a one of the projects (a class library). This caused some errors in another project (an ASP.Net WebApi project) because it also needed the reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` to be updated.

The error was thrown at run-time not compile-time and I had to manually install `Newtonsoft.Json` on each of the projects within the solution.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

This lead me to wonder if it is possible to update all third party libraries at solution level?

I know you can create a folder to store the libraries and add that to the source control but I would like to avoid that.

I want Nuget to download the libraries after fetching the solution from the repository. I was wondering if it is possible to:

1. Create a new project in the solution called something like `www.solution.com.thirdparty`
2. Add reference to all third party software using nuget
3. Expose the all third party libraries via `www.solution.com.thirdparty`

I don't know how can I do the third step and I would also know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use packages at solution level, as described [in this post](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/04/21/nuget-tip-3-manage-packages-at-the-solution-level/).

Alternatively you can have a look at [Paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/), it has a nice transitive dependency resolution algorithm that may work for you.